# HDR color-space transformations result in negative RGB values (Yxy to XYZ to sRGB)

Tags: matrix, color-space, srgb, hdr

I'm currently adding HDR to an old engine and stumbled on a color-space transformation problem.

1. I'm defining my lights in the Yxy color space
2. Then I'm converting Yxy to XYZ
3. XYZ to sRGB transformation.
4. Using RGB values > 1.0 when rendering and normalizing the result with tone mapping in the end.

I'm working with rather huge numbers since the main light source is the sun having up to 150k Lux Illuminance.

YxyToXYZ function

```
osg::Vec3 YxyToXYZ( const osg::Vec3& Yxy )
{
    if ( Yxy[2] > 0.0f )
    {
        return osg::Vec3( Yxy[0] * Yxy[1] / Yxy[2] , Yxy[0] , Yxy[0] * ( 1.0f - Yxy[1] - Yxy[2])  / Yxy[2] );
    }
    else
    {
        return osg::Vec3( 0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f );   
    }
}
```

XYZtosRGB

```
osg::Vec3 XYZToSpectralRGB( const osg::Vec3& XYZ )
{
    // Wikipedia matrix
    osg::Vec3 rgb;
    rgb[0] = 3.240479  * XYZ[0] - 1.537150 * XYZ[1] - 0.498535 * XYZ[2];
    rgb[1] = -0.969256 * XYZ[0] + 1.875992 * XYZ[1] + 0.041556 * XYZ[2];
    rgb[2] = 0.055648 * XYZ[0]  - 0.204043 * XYZ[1] + 1.057311 * XYZ[2];

    std::cout << "newrgb rgb r:" << rgb[0] << " g:" << rgb[1] << " b:" << rgb[2] << std::endl;

    // The matrix in pbrt book p. 235 gives unexpected results. We expect that if we have
    // x = y = 0.33333 we get a white pixel but that matrix gives red. Hence we use a different
    // matrix that is often used by 3D people
    rgb[0] = 2.5651  * XYZ[0] -1.1665 * XYZ[1] -0.3986 * XYZ[2];
    rgb[1] = -1.0217 * XYZ[0] + 1.9777 * XYZ[1] + 0.0439 * XYZ[2];
    rgb[2] = 0.0753 * XYZ[0]  -0.2543 * XYZ[1] + 1.1892 * XYZ[2];

    std::cout << "oldrgb rgb r:" << rgb[0] << " g:" << rgb[1] << " b:" << rgb[2] << std::endl;

    return rgb;
}
```

Test samples:

```
Yxy Y:1 x:1 y:1
XYZ X:1 Y:1 Z:-1
newrgb rgb r:2.20186 g:0.86518 b:-1.20571
oldrgb rgb r:1.7972  g:0.9121  b:-1.3682

Yxy Y:25 x:0.26 y:0.28
XYZ X:23.2143 Y:25 Z:41.0714
newrgb rgb r:16.3211 g:26.106  b:39.616
oldrgb rgb r:14.0134 g:27.5275 b:44.2327

Yxy Y:3100 x:0.27 y:0.29
XYZ X:2886.21 Y:3100 Z:4703.45
newrgb rgb r:2242.7  g:3213.56 b:4501.09
oldrgb rgb r:1912.47 g:3388.51 b:5022.34

Yxy Y:6e+06 x:0.33 y:0.33
XYZ X:6e+06 Y:6e+06 Z:6.18182e+06
newrgb rgb r:7.13812e+06 g:5.69731e+06 b:5.64573e+06
oldrgb rgb r:5.92753e+06 g:6.00738e+06 b:6.27742e+06
```

**Question:**

1. I suppose negative values should be just clamped away? Or do i have a error in my calculations?
2. The 2 matrices produce similar but different values (primaries very close to sRGB). I would like to replace the old matrix (which I have no idea where it's coming from) with the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) one. Does anyone know where the old matrix is coming from and which would be the correct one?
3. I found a partial answer @ [Yxy to RGB conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104034/yxy-to-rgb-conversion) which sounds like from a former colleague :)... but doesn't solve my problems.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `newrgb rgb` computations are correct, I get the same output using [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour):

```python
import colour

xyY = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
XYZ = colour.xyY_to_XYZ(xyY)
print(colour.XYZ_to_sRGB(XYZ, apply_encoding_cctf=False))

xyY = (0.26, 0.28, 25.0)
XYZ = colour.xyY_to_XYZ(xyY)
print(colour.XYZ_to_sRGB(XYZ, apply_encoding_cctf=False))

xyY = (0.27, 0.29, 3100.0)
XYZ = colour.xyY_to_XYZ(xyY)
print(colour.XYZ_to_sRGB(XYZ, apply_encoding_cctf=False))

xyY = (0.33, 0.33, 6e+06)
XYZ = colour.xyY_to_XYZ(xyY)
print(colour.XYZ_to_sRGB(XYZ, apply_encoding_cctf=False))

# [ 2.2020461   0.86530782 -1.20530687]
# [ 16.31921754  26.10605109  39.60507773]
# [ 2242.49706509  3213.58480355  4499.85141917]
# [ 7138073.69325106  5697605.86069197  5644291.15301836]
```

You get negative values in the first conversion because your `xy` chromaticity coordinates are outside the spectral locus, thus they represent imaginary colours.

The Wikipedia matrix is correct and is the one from `IEC 61966-2-1:1999` which is the official standard for `sRGB` colourspace.

Comment: Many thanks for verifying my values! What I'm still not sure about is this description in the [matrix table](http://brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html) 
**In order to properly use this matrix, the RGB values must be linear and in the nominal range [0.0, 1.0]**
Does that mean I have to divide my Yxy values by 150k since that would be the maximum lux value, then doing the matrix calculation, then multiplying by 65504 to achieve [correct conversion](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=01#text1)

Comment: That is a good question actually, the RGB values have to be linear for sure, now regarding the normalisation, I'll be honest, I don't see a clear reason why it would be needed in a floating point processing chain. It might make a bit more sense in 8-bit or any integer processing chain since you want to optimise code allocation to avoid quantization artefacts. In your context I would avoid that normalisation.